# C2732 - Linkage specification error

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, extern

I'm using VS2008. I'm getting the following error.

```
BUILD: [02:0000000295:ERRORE] c:\wince700\platform\am33x_bsp\src\bootloader\bootpart\bootpart_e.cpp(61) : error C2732: linkage specification contradicts earlier specification for 'SdhcInitialize' {log="C:\WINCE700\platform\AM33X_BSP\SRC\BOOTLOADER\bldsys.log(103)"}
BUILD: [02:0000000297:ERRORE] NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\WINCE700\sdk\bin\i386\ARM\cl.EXE' : return code '0x2' {log="C:\WINCE700\platform\AM33X_BSP\SRC\BOOTLOADER\bldsys.log(104)"}
BUILD: [02:0000000299:ERRORE]  clean TargetCompilePass  -nologo BUILDMSG=Stop.  BUILDROOT=C:\WINCE700\platform\AM33X_BSP CLEANBUILD=1 NOLINK=1 NOPASS0=1 failed - rc = 2. {log="C:\WINCE700\platform\AM33X_BSP\SRC\BOOTLOADER\bldsys.log(105)"}
```

**file_1.cpp**

```
extern "C"
{
   // some extern declarations
   extern void SdhcInitialize(DWORD slot);
}
```

**file_2.c**

```
void SdhcInitialize(DWORD slot)
{
//some code
}
```

Please guide me how to resolve.

Comment: What is `SD_API_STATUS`? And is there more written in the error log? Please update the question to include the complete (and unedited) log.

Comment: Are you sure there are no other declarations/definitions of `SdhcInitialize`?

Comment: I'm assuming that is a status code return type, not a macro with declaration specifiers.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It is just a structure. But, for simplicity I have updated my question with `void`. Also, I have included the unedited log. Thanks.

Comment: @user694733 In the file_1.cpp, No. There is only one declaration of it. But, in one `.c` file, that function has been declared without "C" in extern. Does it involve in this?

Comment: Are your other declarations missing `extern` or having `static`? Are you including `.c` files in `.cpp` files (like `#include "file_2.c"` in some C++ file`). Why not have header `file_2.h` with needed `extern` declarations, which would be included to other files, instead of having externs all over the place like you have now?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have a header that contains a prototype for the `SdhcInitialize()` function, and that the header was written for use by C programs. So for example, the header file might include something like the following line:

```
SD_API_STATUS SdhcInitialize(DWORD slot);
```

without being enclosed in an `extern "C" {}` block (since the header is intended for C programs).

Additionally, I suspect that this header is being included - directly or indirectly - by `file_1.cpp`

This means that the header cannot be included in a C++ program without some additional work being done, otherwise the C++ program will see the declaration as meaning that `SdhcInitialize()` has C++ linkage.

You have two reasonable approaches to fixing this:

- if you can modify the header, add the following lines around the declarations in the header:

  ```
    #if __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif

    // declarations go here

    #if __cplusplus
    }
    #endif
  ```

  This way, C++ files will have the declarations enclosed in a `extern "C"` linkage block, while C program will not see the `extern "C"` bits (which would otherwise confuse the C compiler).

  I think an argument can be made that all C headers should include something like those lines so that the C functions can be consumed by C++ programs without hassle.
- if you cannot modify the header for some reason, you can work around the problem by including the header in C++ files like so:

  ```
    extern "C" {
    #include "Sdhc-header.h"
    }
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I have included `__cplusplus` as mentioned, but error persists. You have mentioned `I suspect that this header is being included - directly or indirectly - by file_1.cpp`. Actually, I have another file which has `.c` extension, wherein I have just declared extern without "C". Is it any kind of reason behind this error?

Comment: Does `bootpart_e.cpp` include some file (including indirectly) that declares `SdhcInitialize()`.  If you have trouble determining this, using the `/P` option will send the preprocessor output to a file and you can search that file for all instances of `SdhcInitialize` to see where the declarations are coming from.

Answer (score 2):

If you surround a set of function declaration by `extern "C" { ... }`, you don't need to use an additionnal `extern`keyword in front of the function identifier.

```
extern "C"
{
   // some extern declarations
   SD_API_STATUS SdhcInitialize(DWORD slot);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But, even removing that extern doesn't make any changes to that error.

Comment: I got the same warning, when I used a "double extern", the warning disappear when I remove one extern, but WHY ?, the `extern "C"` is different than `extern` ?

Answer (score 2):

When you try to include the "some header files of C" file in "C++ file"(the header file has some where `extern "C"` for some functions).

include the header earlier will solve the problem.

e.g. Try to move `#include "myHeader.h"` on the top lines of your C++ file.

This solves my problems.

Hope it helps....

Comment: This work for me, thanks! (Although I don't really know why Q_Q)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this as follows (the other solutions did not work for me):

In the file vector.cc:

```
#define __INVECTOR //solves 
#include "vector.h"
```

In vector.h:

```
#ifndef __INVECTOR
void function(...etc..);
#endif
```

This way the declaration isn't read unless we want to call the function from a different file.